# Jenkins build fail - Error: not found: make

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline, npm-install

I try to create CI for my npm module, but I have the problem with NPM install command. I try to globally install gyp but nothing works for me. Is it problem with dependencies (package.json file is added after console output) or some configurations on jenkins is missing? **Node version is 11.6.0**.

Console output :

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/current_node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/current_node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/current_node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/current_node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/current_node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/current_node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:160:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64
gyp ERR! command "/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/current_node/bin/node" "/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/current_node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/jenkins_home/workspace/defined-id/defined-id/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v11.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN defined-id@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN The package js-sha256 is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bufferutil@3.0.5 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bufferutil@3.0.5 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/jenkins_home/.npm/_logs/2019-03-19T08_59_17_472Z-debug.log
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Package.json

```
{
    "name": "defined-id",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "lib/index.js",
    "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest --config jestconfig.json",
        "build": "tsc",
        "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"src/**/*.js\"",
        "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json",
        "prepare": "yarn run build",
        "prepublishOnly": "yarn test && yarn run lint",
        "preversion": "yarn run lint",
        "version": "yarn run format && git add -A src",
        "postversion": "git push && git push --tags"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git"
    },
    "author": "Geens NPO",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/jest": "^23.3.9",
        "jest": "^23.6.0",
        "js-sha256": "^0.9.0",
        "prettier": "^1.15.2",
        "ts-jest": "^23.10.5",
        "ts-node": "^8.0.3",
        "tslint": "^5.11.0",
        "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.16.0",
        "typescript": "^3.1.6"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
        "@types/uuid": "^3.4.4",
        "base-58": "0.0.1",
        "base58check": "^2.0.0",
        "create-hmac": "^1.1.7",
        "js-sha256": "^0.9.0",
        "jsonld": "^1.4.0",
        "key-encoder": "^1.1.7",
        "nem2-sdk": "0.10.2",
        "ripemd160": "^2.0.2",
        "tweetnacl": "^1.0.1",
        "tweetnacl-util": "^0.15.0"
    }
}
```

Execute shell :

```
npm install --prefix defined-id
npm run build --prefix defined-id
npm run test --prefix defined-id
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: not found: make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125789/error-not-found-make)

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that is not a Jenkins error.

Execute the following line in the Linux where NPM commands are executed:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

And build again your Jenkins job.

Comment: [Generally, one doesn't want to `sudo npm`](https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92)

Comment: I Don’t Use sudo with npm, I use sudo to install the required software in order to fix the error: **Error: not found: make**

Comment: The problem is that a required software is missing at operative system level.