# Enmap won't install with better-sqlite3 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have been trying to install enmap for a while now, I have searched the web and haven't found any working solutions, I am trying `npm i enmap` and I keep getting this error:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/d993WptFyq/

A part of the error that sticks out to me is this

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:168:21)
```

I don't know what any of it means.

I have deleted my module folder and package files and keep getting this same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: not found: make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125789/error-not-found-make)

Comment: no, i didn't get a real answer from that.

Comment: Delete your lock file and run it again

Comment: @Jytesh just did, same error

Comment: here is a video  https://enragedextralargeline.shawndoes.repl.co/video.webm

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed this issue, i needed to install `build-essential` using `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Answer (score 0):

> Error: not found: make

You need to install make:

```
sudo apt install make
```

In most case you need `gcc` too:

```
sudo apt install gcc
```

If you want to install all the libraries and programs you might need on any install (not just `better-sqlite3`), you can install `build-essential`:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```